# How to paste and retain the data validation of the cell or code validation in (text only and limit number of characters to 10)?

Tags: excel, vba

Code below pastes clipboard content. Problem is it bypasses cell validation.

1. How to paste and retain the data validation of the cell?
2. Or, better yet, add validation into code below -- text only and limit number of characters to 10 (alphanumeric)?

```
    Public Clipboard As New MSForms.DataObject
    Sub Paste()
    'Tools -> References -> Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library
    'or you will get a "Compile error: user-defined type not defined"
    Dim DataObj As New MSForms.DataObject
    Dim S As String
    DataObj.GetFromClipboard
    S = DataObj.GetText
    'Debug.Print S 'print code in the Intermediate box in the Macro editor
    Target.Value = S
    End Sub
```

Using above code with:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
 If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("k4:s8")) Is Nothing Then
 Cancel = True
 Call Paste
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you share more detail and code so we can see for ourselves that using this object is really necessary? What is `Target`? Its declaration is nowhere to be found. BTW if Target is one cell, you could use the one-liner `If Len(S) > 10 Then Target.Value = Left(S, 10) Else Target.Value = S` or the `IIf` version `Target.Value = IIf(Len(S) > 10, Left(S, 10), S)`.

Comment: Additionally, you need to use `Sub Paste(ByVal Target As Range)` and instead of `Call Paste` use `Paste Target` (the `Call` keyword is considered deprecated).

Comment: @VBasic2008 - thanks.  Updated post to include other relevant code I'm using.  Your proposed code seems to intend to post only portion, if clipboard exceeds the validation limit and cut off the rest, correct?  I'd like to ensure, if limit is exceeded, a warning comes up instead.  And in part this is to ensure a picture snapshot, for example, is not pasted there, but text only and limit number of characters to 10 (alphanumeric).

Comment: Please add the information in your last comment and any additional information to your post. Explain the picture part in more detail and add some examples of strings that should be returned for the initial string e.g. for `ABC . .DE=#FG1(!)2#3ABC` it should return `ABCDEFG123`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 - thanks. Just in case if user happen to have a picture on the clipboard's last item, for it NOT to be pasted, and a warning to come up instead pointing that out.  Any text, including special characters are okay, just give a warning if in excess of 10 characters, don't cut them off. Maybe a MsgBox with option to NOT paste, to cut down to left 10 or to paste and give length of how many about to be pasted.